# Bootstrap- how to align 5 images in different alignment?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a layout for the view and I want to arrange my image in this way below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I created my alignment and plan to use a row with two columns but so far my top left two pictures and the one below is are space out far apart and I can't get it to look like the image. The two right picture are also space out apart.

Below is my code:

```
<section class="learn_more">
    <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 d-flex ">
                <div class="container">
                <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" alt="" style="margin-top:100px; margin-left:20px;" />

                <div class="text-block">
                    <h4>Nature</h4>
                    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
                </div>       
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Pillow.jpg')}}" alt="" style="margin-top:100px; height:55%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" >
                <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Kitchen.jpg')}}" alt="" style="margin-top:120px; margin-left:50px;" /> 

    </div>



            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <img src="{{asset('/images/Shop_Page.jpg')}}" alt="No Logo" style="margin-left:40px; margin-bottom:100px;" />
        </div>




            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" >
            <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Sofa.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width:100%; margin-left:150px;" /> 

             </div>


    </div
```

Is there a mistake I made?
>

Comment: This is called `masonry` please refer the link on how to implement it https://masonry.desandro.com/
also refer https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Is it possible to work on it with bootstrap rows/columns?

Comment: check the link https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/layout/bootstrap-masonry/ and here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/KXlEg

Comment: This can be possible with rows but only for static data.

Comment: @AkhilAravind So I don't need to install anything?

Comment: @LordJesus I guess so, can you go through the link provided

Comment: @AkhilAravind I did but now i am trying to make it look like the picture i posted

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this also I also recommend using masonry.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm custom-position">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col col-8">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/700x300" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="col">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.row {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

*[class*="col"] {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block; 
}

.col-8 {
  height: 350px;
}

*[class*="col"] img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.custom-position {
 position: relative;
 bottom: -100px;
}
```

Note that if you go with this option you should fit images with `object-fit` so you could use different sizes.

Comment: Does it give me the layout i want?

Comment: But it does not fit the end of the screen

Comment: It does give you the layout that you want. I don't know what you mean by 'end of the screen'. Anyway, you should copy and paste this in Codepen and play with this in order to understand the grid.

Comment: If the `boxes` are small, can i change the height/width so my image looks bigger?

Comment: @LordJesus I updated the CSS code, So now you have the custom height for the boxes (columns) and you can put different image sizes and it will work. Note that you should use custom wrapper inside columns because it's not good practice to use columns for anything except grid style. I hope this will help.

Comment: Actually I have a navigation bar and footer so it went off the grid, not really working.

Comment: Use Bootstrap 4 and check your grid. This code is working on Codepen so obviously the problem is in your code.