# css 3 grid- how to align images?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS 3 Grid to make some specific placement of my home page using images I imported.
This is what I am looking to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have on my grid at the moment:

[image]

This my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="bed"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
    <div class="pillow"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
    <div class="kitchen"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
    <div class="living-room"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
    <div class="sofa"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>


</div>

@endsection

@push('style')
<style>

.wrapper{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr 1fr ;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px,auto);
    padding: 1em;
}


.wrapper >div{

padding: 1em;

}

.bed{

 height: 50%;


}

.pillow{

 height: 50%;
 width:100%;

}
.kitchen{
    height: 50%;
}

.living-room{
    height: 70%;
    width:150%;
}

.sofa{
    height: 50%;
    width:150%;

}

img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

How do I arrange my images so that it should be aligned identically like the expected outcome?

Updated::

[image]

Comment: You opened the same question yesterday...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648583/bootstrap-how-to-align-5-images-in-different-alignment/60648954#60648954

Comment: Because the solution did not work and did not get enough response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap- how to align 5 images in different alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648583/bootstrap-how-to-align-5-images-in-different-alignment)

Comment: Nope, the aligment does not fit the entire screen and it looks very off in mobile layout. Tried tweaking with the settings but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I removed the `800px/600px` explicit height and the grid fills the entire screen by default.

---

For simplicity, I stretched all the images to fill their entire grid cell. The thing to look at is how the `grid-row` and `grid-column` values are working. By specifying how far each grid cell should span, the height and width is naturally distributed throughout the grid. For this example, I set the grid to be `800px` wide and `600px` tall.

I'm using `fr` units for the grid rules, so they will distribute relatively based on their relationship to other children. The following line tells the browser to make the grid 8 units long. The first column will be 3/8 of the total width (`800px` in this example). The second column looked a narrower than the others so I made it `2fr`.

```css
grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 3fr;
```

When you see a `-1` in a grid child measurement, it means essentially, *go to the end*. For example, the following snippet says to start at row line 3 and span to the end, however many lines there are.

```css
grid-row: 3 / -1;
```

**Demo**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  padding: 1em;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper>div {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.bed {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.bed::after {
  content: 'BED';
}

.pillow {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.pillow::after {
  content: 'PILLOW';
}

.kitchen {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.kitchen::after {
  content: 'KITCHEN';
}

.living-room {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

.living-room::after {
  content: 'LIVING ROOM';
}

.sofa {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
}

.sofa::after {
  content: 'SOFA';
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="bed"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="pillow"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="kitchen"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="living-room"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="sofa"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>

</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdcku1fL/)

Comment: Is this grid supposed to be responsive? How does it look like in mobile layout?

Comment: While your solution works, I need to set it to fit the screen of my desktop browser as it is only occupying 1/3 of the screen.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong but when it fills the entire screen, the width and height doesn't seem natural. I can't see all the 5 images without scrolling down. Can you take a look ? I updated my post.

Comment: Setting this in my wrapper seem to make it look better. width: 2000px;
  height: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;

Comment: @LordJesus Not sure how else to help you. You can set `max-height` and `max-width` or set an explicit height for the grid itself. Otherwise, it's functioning as designed. For mobile, set a media query and update grid child rules at the break-point.